# Using character set en_us.364 in Informix database DB_LOCALE

Tags: configuration, character-set, informix

I am trying to change my `db_locale` to `en_us.364` which is an ASCII character set. It says on IBM's Knowledge Center that 364 is a valid character set:

- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/ids_jdbc_270.htm

I am able to change my `DB_LOCALE=en_us.364`. However, after changing the `db_locale` to `en_us.364` I cannot access `dbaccess`. I get this error:

> -23101 Unable to load locale categories.

So I also tried changing my `client_locale` to `en_us.364` as well. I was able to set the environment variable. However it still gave the same error when trying to use `dbaccess`.

I then looked around in the `GLS/lc11/en_us` and could not find `016c.lco` which is the character set 364/ASCII. However, I have found this character set in the `GLS/lc11/pl_pl` folder which means that ASCII is supported. I was wondering where I could get either the `016c.lco` or the `016c.lc` for the locale `en_us`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better or worse (and mostly worse), although some of the files necessary to support `en_us.364` are present, the file needed in `lc11/en_us` is not present.  Thus, you can have `de_de.364` or `es_es.364` or `fr_fr.364` or `pl_pl.364` but you can't have `en_us.364`.

You have a few options at this point.

1. One is to try downloading the ILS — International Language Supplement.  This has many extra locales in it; it might have `en_us.364` (but no promises).
2. Another is to try copying an existing locale (maybe `gls/lc11/fr_fr/016c.lco` or `gls/lc11/de_de/016c.lco` to `gls/lc11/en_us/016c.lco`. You'd probably want to edit the LANGUAGE and TERRITORY lines.  However, be aware that the French and German locales are different; it will matter which you choose.
3. Report a problem to IBM Informix Tech Support, requesting the file for `gls/lc11/en_us/016c.lco`.

I'm not sure which is best.  If the relevant file *is* in the ILS, then that's simple.  Copying a locale file is mostly straight-forward, but you need to consider what will happen if that's not available.

Comment: It does not look like the ILS-International Language Supplement has the locale en_us.364. Here is the documentation from IBM's website: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.cliapinode.doc/ils_ug.htm